# Finding difference of two columns from two different rows in an SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out a query which returns difference of two columns that belongs to two different rows of single table

For Example I have the following data in a table

```
id      Market  Grade       Term     Bid     Offer
1       Heavy   ABC         Jun14   -19.5     -17
2       Heavy   ABC         Jul14   -20      -17.5
3       Sour    XYZ         Jun14   -30       -17
4       Sour    XYZ         Jul14   -32       -27
```

Now, I want the following results

(AS `Market` and `Grade` are same for `Id=1,2`)

```
Bid of Id=1 - Offer of Id=2
Offer of Id=1- Bid of Id=2
```

(AS `Market` and `Grade` are same for `Id=3,4`)

```
Bid of Id=3 - Offer of Id=4
Offer of Id=3- Bid of Id=4
```

Something Like the following

```
Market     Term          Bid                   Offer
Heavy/ABC  Jun14/Jul14   (-19.5-(-17.5))=-2    (-17-(-20))=3
Sour/XYZ  Jun14/Jul14    (-30-(-27))=-3        (-17-(-32))=15
```

What would be that vest way to do it MS SQL.

Comment: What happens if you have 3 or more rows for the same `Market` and `Grade`?

Comment: That doesn't happen in my data as to perform that calculation the Term should be next to each other like in the question it is Jun14 and Jul14 and there will be only one record for each term

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [row_number function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
create table things
(id int, Market varchar(30), Grade varchar(30), Term varchar(30), Bid decimal, Offer decimal)

insert into things values
(1,'Heavy','ABC','Jun14',-19.5 , -17)
,(2,'Heavy','ABC','Jul14',-20   ,-17.5)
,(3,'Sour','XYZ','Jun14',-30   , -17)
,(4,'Sour','XYZ','Jul14',-32   , -27)

;with numbered as
(
    select id, market, grade, term, bid, offer, row_number() OVER (Partition BY Market, Grade ORDER BY Bid desc) i
    from things
)
--select * from numbered
select r1.market + '/' + r1.grade as Market, r1.term + '/' + r2.term as Term, r1.Bid - r2.Offer [Bid], r1.Offer - r2.Bid [Offer] 
from numbered r1 
join numbered r2 on r1.market = r2.market and r1.grade = r2.grade and r1.i < r2.i
```

Comment: Do I need to insert data into a table every time there is a change to my data in my original table?

Comment: No, I just put the table creation and insertion statements in there so it would be easy for people to try this out themselves. So you can ignore those (since you already have them).

Comment: It almost worked fine but for some data it is giving the reverse data like Jul14/Jun14 instead of Jun14/Jul14. I thought problem was with r1.i<r2.i

Comment: Anyways I got it. I just ordered by Term.  Thanks